# Serial-Load-Shift-Register

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In the `serial load shift register`, how can i **make sure that the shift was not disabled before at least five data has been loaded**?

```
module serial_load_shift_register(
  input logic clk         ,
  input logic shift_enable,
  input logic d_in        ,
  output logic q
);
  logic [0:4] register;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    register[0] <= shift_enable ? d_in        : register[0];
    register[1] <= shift_enable ? register[0] : register[1];
    register[2] <= shift_enable ? register[1] : register[2];
    register[3] <= shift_enable ? register[2] : register[3];
    register[4] <= shift_enable ? register[3] : register[4];
  end
  assign q = register[4];
endmodule: serial_load_shift_register
```

Comment: Simulate the design to verify it meet the requirements.

Comment: Five data starting from when?

Comment: @dave_59, I'm referring that once the enable is set to 1, it will remain on this value for at least the following 5 clock pulses before reset to 0.

Comment: I apologize if the English isn't perfect; it's not my first language, and I'm doing my best to express the question.

Comment: There is no problem with your English; people have the same problems asking questions regardless of which language is their first. You were missing pieces of information. I have one more question about your question: when you ask "_How do I make sure...?_", do you mean "_how do I modify/correct the design to behave this way_?" or do you mean "_How do I check/verify that once `shift_enable` goes to 1, it stays 1 fore at least 5 clock cycle?_"

Comment: @dave_59 Yes, I meant that how can I change the code to achieve what I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is put the `shift_enable` signal into a shift register as well that gives you a *history* of that signal. If that register is non-zero, use that condition to control the shifting of data.

```
module serial_load_shift_register(
  input logic clk         ,
  input logic shift_enable,
  input logic d_in        ,
  output logic q
);
  logic [0:3] register;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    logic [0:4] enable;
    enable = {enable,shift_enable};
    if (enable != 0) register <= {register, d_in};
  end
  assign q = register[0];
 
endmodule: serial_load_shift_register
```

Note that the assignment to `enable` is not using an NBA. This means the statements that references `enable` following the assignment use the current value, not the value from the previous cycle. There are no issues with race conditions because I declared `enable` local to the `always` block, so no one can reference it outside the `always`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. In general you need a kind of a counter which will be used to keep your enable alive for a number of cycles. As an example, you can have another register which shifts the value of the enable signal for 5 cycles or so. Here is an example.

```
module serial_load_shift_register(
  input logic clk         ,
  input logic reset,
  input logic shift_enable,
  input logic d_in        ,
  output logic q
);
  logic [4:0] register;
  logic [4:0] enable_validator;
  
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      enable_valida <= 0;
      register <= 0;
    end
    else begin
       enable_valid <= (enable_valid << 1) | shift_enable;
    
       if (|enable_valid)  begin
          register <= (register << 1) | d_in;
       end
    end
  end
  assign q = register[4];
endmodule: serial_load_shift_register
```

In the above example *enable_valid* is such a register. It keeps *enable* flag alive while any of its bits is non-zero, allowing the *register* to keep shifting even if the *enable_shift* signal disappears.

I did a couple of updates to your code. First, I added a 'reset' which is needed to initialize some values. Also, I replaced your bit-by-bit shift with a shift operator `<<`.

You just need to figure out timing relation between different signals in your model and tune the code up to your needs.

Here is a *sample* test bench to quick test of the above.

```
module tb;
  logic clk, reset, shift_enable, d_in, q;
 
  serial_load_shift_register shifter(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .shift_enable(shift_enable), .d_in(d_in), .q(q));
  
  initial begin 
    clk = 0;
    forever #2 clk = !clk;
  end
  
  initial begin
    reset = 0;
    d_in = 0;
    shift_enable = 0;
    
    #4 reset = 1;
    #4 reset = 0;
    #4 d_in = 1;
    #4 shift_enable = 1;
    #8 shift_enable = 0;
       d_in = 0;
    #30 $finish;
  end
  
  always @* begin
    $display("%0t> clk %b, shift_enable = %b, d_in = %b, q ==> %b (%b %b)", $time, clk, shift_enable, d_in, q,
            shifter.enable_validator, shifter.register);
  end
endmodule
```